# pip is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip

Im trying to install google assistant on my Raspberry Pi, but when I keep getting an error: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: @jwodder `python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library`
The error I get is:
`/home/pi/env/bin/python: cannot import name HashMissing: 'pip is a package and cannot be directly executed `

Comment: Which version of `pip` do you have?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I'm not sure sorry, How would I check?

Comment: @CiaranFinnegan: To get the version of `pip`: `pip --version`.

Comment: You might have accidentally removed `pip`, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
pip [...]
```

Try doing

```
python -m pip [...]
```

Can't really help more without more info.

Comment: That's what I had been trying.  
`python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library` resulted in:  
`/home/pi/env/bin/python: cannot import name HashMissing: 'pip is a package and cannot be directly executed`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of `pip` is old. You need to upgrade it first, like this:

```
pip install -U pip
```

You may need to upgrade setuptools too:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Since `google-assistant-library` is available as a wheel, you need to install `wheel` too:

```
pip install wheel
```

I don't know if you can do that with Raspberry Pi, but I recommend you to used a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). That way, you have a fresh and isolated Python executable and a recent version of `pip`.

```
virtualenv your_proj
source your_proj/bin/activate
pip install wheel
pip install google-assistant-library
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer version ie. using pip3:

```
pip3 install -U <<package name>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I think it was an outcome of a failed

```
> .\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

do to some environment misconfiguration.
So it first removed the existing version 10.0.1, and then the installation of the new version 22.3.1 failed, leaving me with no `pip`.

From [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), I ran

```
> .\python.exe -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

which restored the original pip 10.0.1.
Then I fixed the environment problem, and then again

```
> .\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I now have pip 22.3.1.